# Can github execute status checks conditionally on outdated branch?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

We have github enterprise 2.13.4.

For a particular repo, we have a number of status checks. I'm not the repo admin so I don't have access to the definition of the checks themselves.

One of the checks executes a build on Jenkins.

For this repo, merges are not allowed unless the branch is up to date.

For the build that executes on Jenkins, there are several devops scripts that facilitate the build, and one of those scripts aborts the build when it determines that the branch is out of date.

The problem is that this takes a couple minutes to reach that conclusion, and for the overall list of builds on that Jenkins server, half are failed due to this exact scenario, cluttering the list of builds for that job.

Desired behavior for these PRs:

- retain the enforcement of not merging until up to date
- retain the enforcement of all status checks passing before merging
- conditionally run the "build" status check only if the branch is already up to date. If the PR creator creates it out of date with the target branch, they can simply update, and do a "retest this please", etc.

Right now, the build aborts anyway after a couple minutes of wasted time on the build agent before proceeding to anything meaningful, so I don't think what I'm proposing would remove any valuable information (compile error, etc) that would have been provided on building a branch even if it were out of date.